# NET6 Linux-x64 Self-Contained Single-File Unusable

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I've a project that runs perfectly as "Framework-Dependent Single-File" on Linux-x64, and also as a "Self-Contained" application.

But when I compile as "Self-Contained Single-File", the Visual Studio 2022 (17.1.2) creates a file without any extension (exe or dll), and I cannot run it anyway on Ubuntu 21.x.

When I call it, I always get an "invalid application" error. I tried:

- dotnet myproject
- dotnet myproject.dll  (adding the DLL extension manually before the call)
- dotnet myproject.exe  (adding the EXE extension manually before the call)

Is there something I could be doing wrong?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: If it's self-contained, you shouldn't need to use `dotnet`. It should just be `myproject` or possibly `./myproject`.

Comment: Wow! "./" had solved the problem! If you want, please add the answer to I mark it - thanks a lot @HereticMonkey!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610128/net6-linux-x64-self-contained-single-file-unusable#comment126561456_71610128) stated, you need to run it with `./`NAME

Also you need to make sure that the user has Execute permissions for that file. See [chown/chmod](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/)